# Automated testing feels a lot like duplicating the tested logic, am I doing it right?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, tdd

I'm implementing automated testing with CppUTest in C++.
I realize I end up almost copying and pasting the logic to be tested on the tests themselves, so I can check the expected outcomes.
Am I doing it right? should it be otherwise?

edit: I'll try to explain better:
The unit being tested takes input *A*, makes some processing and returns output *B*
So apart from making some black box checks, like checking that the output lies in an expectable range, I would also like to see if the output *B* that I got is the right outcome for input *A* I.E. if the logic is working as expected.
So for example if the unit just makes *A* times 2 to yield *B*, then in the test I have no other way of checking than making again the calculation of *A* times 2 to check against *B* to be sure it went alright.
That's the duplication I'm talking about.

```
// Actual function being tested:  
int times2( int a )
{
  return a * 2;
}
```

.

```
// Test:
int test_a;
int expected_b = test_a * 2; // here I'm duplicating times2()'s logic
int actual_b = times2( test_a );
CHECK( actual_b == expected_b );
```

.

PS: I think I will reformulate this in another question with my actual source code.

Comment: Why would you copy the logic? The logic is what you're testing--*call* the logic from your tests. If you're testing *chunks* of logic and going through setups to get to the point where you can call, then without knowing what's actually being tested, it's harder to help.

Comment: @Dave yes, I am calling the logic of course, but I have to check the inputs and outputs of the unit being tested against something else.

Comment: This reminds me the situation when my manager asked me to implement 100% test automation. We cannot write a logic to calculate the expected (final) result of test case. It would be recreating the function what development team did. If you think of bigger problematic scenario, you can supply either hard-coded outcome or simple calculated expected result to get maximum out of Test automation. Answer to your question would be 'yes', if we keep developing the same logic inside testing function as that of function under test.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to build automated tests for your existing code, you're probably doing it wrong. Hopefully you know what the result of frobozz.Gonkulate() should be for various inputs and can write tests to check that Gonkulate() is returning the right thing. If you have to copy Gonkulate()'s convoluted logic to figure out the answer, you might want to ask yourself how well you understand the logic to begin with.

If you're trying to do test-driven development, you're **definitely** doing it wrong. TDD consists of many quick cycles of:

1. Writing a test
2. Watching it fail
3. Making it pass
4. Refactoring as necessary to improve the overall design

Step 1 - writing the test **first** - is an essential part of TDD. I infer from your question that you're writing the code first and the tests later.

Comment: yes I know, but I decided to use automated testing after I already had started coding. I'm writing tests for what's written now, and then will start to write tests first.
I'll try to explain better in an edit

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Michael Feathers' book _Working Effectively With Legacy Code_ is a great resource for getting code originally written without tests under control; I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

> So for example if the unit just makes A times 2 to yield B, then in
>   the test I have no other way of checking than making again the
>   calculation of A times 2 to check against B to be sure it went
>   alright.

Yes you do! You know how to calculate A times two, so you don't need to do this in code. if A is 4 then you *know* the answer is 8. So you can just use it as the expected value.

```
CHECK( actual_b == 8 )
```

if you are worried about magic numbers, don't be. Nobody will be confused about the meaning of the hard coded numbers in the following line:

```
CHECK( times_2(4) == 8 )
```

If you don't know what the result should be then your unit test is useless. If you need to calculate the expected result, then you are either using the same logic as the function, or using an alternate algorithm to work out the result.In the first case, if the logic that you duplicate is incorrect, your test will still pass! In the second case, you are introducing another place for a bug to occur. If a test fails, you will need to work out whether it failed because the function under test has a bug, or if your test method has a bug.

Comment: So the bottom line is: test against static literal values that, of course, are known to be the correct expected values.

Comment: I know what the result should be, the thing is that that *should*  is not a single literal value, but an algorithm. I'm doing 65535 checks on some functions, that's combining every possible value of two 8 bit values which are the function's input. The only way of doing so many tests is automating the calculation of the expected value, If I do it with literal values, couldn't make too many tests.

Comment: @Petruza: You shouldn't check the whole support of the function. That's not testing, that's rather a full specification. You can't check the function on its full input range without rewriting it. Testing consists only of a few example and corner cases, to make sure the logic works.

Comment: for an explanation of how to choose corner cases, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_analysis

Comment: Ok. But couldn't I generate a list of test cases using the logic to be tested? or should I calculate the results by hand always?

Comment: "using the logic to be tested" - no. Because if your logic is incorrect, you tests will still pass. Testing using the logic to be tested is more harmful than not testing at all, because in addition to not testing the correctness of your logic, you are misleading anyone who is tasked with maintaining your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is a though to crack because it's essentially a mentality shift. It was somewhat hard for me.

The thing about tests is to have your expectancies nailed down and check if your code really does what you think it does. Think in ways of exercising it, not checking its logic so directly, but as a whole. If that's too hard, maybe your function/method just does too much.

Try to think of your tests as working examples of what your code can do, not as a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 1):

The programming language shouldn't matter.

```
 var ANY_NUMBER = 4;
 Assert.That(times_2(ANY_NUMBER), Is.EqualTo(ANY_NUMBER*2)
```

In this case, I wouldn't mind duplicating the logic. The expected value is readable as compared to 8. Second this logic doesn't look like a change-magnet. Relatively static.

For cases, **where the logic is more involved (chunky) and prone to change, duplicating the logic in the test is definitely not recommended**. Duplication is evil. Any change to the logic would ripple changes to the test. In that case, I'd use hardcoded input-expected output pairs with some readable pair-names.

Comment: Ok. I was duplicating the logic instead of checking against static literal values, because I wanted to test every posible input values for their corresponding outcomes.

Comment: @Petruza - int that case I would write a parameterized test (aka RowTests). The same test would be executed against multiple input-output pairs.